# Confidence Intervals for prediction of a logistic generalized linear mixed model (GLMM)

Tags: logistic-regression, effects, lme4, confidence-interval

I am running a logistic generalized linear mixed model and would like to plot my effects together with confidence intervals. 
I use the lme4 package to fit my model:

```
glmer (cbind(positive, negative) ~ F1 * F2 * F3 + V1 + F1 * I(V1^2) + V2 + F1 * I(V2^2) + V3 + I(V3^2) + V4 + I(V4^2) +  F4 + (1|OLRE) + (1|ind), family = binomial, data = try, na.action = na.omit, control=glmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", calc.derivs = FALSE, optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb", starttests = FALSE, kkt = FALSE)))
```

OLRE means that I use an observational level random effect in order to overcome overdispersion.

If you wonder because of convergence warnings, I went through the lme4 troubleshooting protocol, and it should be fine.

In order to get effect plots with confidence intervals, I tried to use ggpredict:
sjPlot, e.g.:

```
 plot_model(mod, type = "pred", terms = c("F1", "F2", "F3"), ci.lvl = 0.95)
```

I also tried to go through this protocol:
https://rpubs.com/hughes/84484

```
 intdata <- expand.grid(
  positive = c(0,1), 
  negative = c(0,1),
  F1 = as.factor(c(0,1)), 
  F2 = as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
  F3= as.factor(c(1,2,3,4)), 
  V1= as.numeric(median(try$V1)),
  F4= as.factor(c(30, 31)), 
  ind= as.factor(c(68)), 
  OLRE = as.factor(c(2450)), 
  V2= as.numeric(median(try$V2)), 
  V3= as.numeric(median(try$V3)), 
  V4= as.numeric(median(try$V4))
  )


 #conditional variances
 cV <- ranef(mod, condVar = TRUE) 
 ranvar <- attr(cV[[1]], "postVar")
 sqrt(diag(ranvar[,,1]))


 mm <- model.matrix(terms(  mod), data=intdata, 
               contrasts.arg = lapply(intdata[,c(3:5, 7:9)], contrasts, contrasts=FALSE))


 predFun<-function(.) mm%*%fixef(.) 
 bb<-bootMer(mod,FUN=predFun,nsim=3)
```

with some problems and warnings regarding contrasts and

```
  Error in mm %*% fixef(.) : non-conformable arguments
```

Therefore, I am wondering if anyone might help me but so far I am not able to  Nothing worked so far, so I would really appreciate some help.

Here the link to the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZaJBbM1ggxwPnZ9bsTCXL7_BnXlvfkW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I managed to solve the problem myself. The OLRE I implemented was a factor. This seemed to cause problems all along the way. When I changed it to be a integer, everything worked out as expected with ggpredict, sjPlot, effects, ...